# OnEntry VBA function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to have a range of cells (Installation Agreement: parts of i column) populated with the number in (Assessment : C4) every time I make an adjustment to the "Job Report" sheet. But it's not updating correctly. Any suggestions?

```
Sub AutoInsertUsage()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Report").OnEntry = "Usage"
End Sub

Sub Usage()
    With Sheets("Installation Agreement")
        .Range("i47:i72") = Sheets("Assessment").Range("c4")
        .Range("i24:i38") = Sheets("Assessment").Range("c4")
        .Range("i41:i44") = Sheets("Assessment").Range("c4")
        .Range("i10:i11") = Sheets("Assessment").Range("c4")
        End With
End Sub
```

PS: The i column cells of the Installation Agreement sheet are locked for editing, otherwise I would simply do "='assessment!'C$4$".

Answer (score 1):

Go into the VBA module for the Job Report tab (right-click on the tab and hit "View Code"), then use the `Worksheet_Change` event as so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sheets("Installation Agreement")
        .Range("i47:i72") = Sheets("Assessment").Range("c4")
        .Range("i24:i38") = Sheets("Assessment").Range("c4")
        .Range("i41:i44") = Sheets("Assessment").Range("c4")
        .Range("i10:i11") = Sheets("Assessment").Range("c4")
    End With
End Sub
```

The `Target` parameter will be populated with the range of cells that were modified, so you can decide from that if the update needs to be done or not.

Comment: Since you are writing to cells in `Worksheet_Change`. Youmight want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)?